# Overflow issue with Superfish Menu when image floated right

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

I am working on a superfish menu that stretches across 100% of the screen. I need to float an image to the right edge of my superfish menu. This image has a dropdown beneath it. My problem is that I am getting overflow on the right hand side, which is causing empty whitespace down the whole view screen. So, my question is... What do I need to do to correct this overflow? I tried hiding the overflow, but then my dropdown doesn't show. I also need to support IE7. There is too much code to paste here, so I have created a JS Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/3AP8q/1/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were subtracting the width of the subnav (line 317 of your css) only on hover so the the subnav was pushed to the right side of your document when resting normally. If you switch that positioning to the initial rule (and add an extra em) the problem is solved:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3AP8q/4/)

Comment: Thanks for looking at that. For some reason, I just couldn't see what was wrong!